# In MVVM, who is responsible for displaying other views, the ViewModel or the View?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, separation-of-concerns

Simple question in regards to a navigation pane like the one used by Outlook.

In MVVM, who is responsible for displaying other views, the ViewModel or the View?

It seems silly to put that code in the ViewModel when the View events can handle calling other views. The ViewModel does enable/disable and show/hide the navigation items as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewModel is responsible for view state. If whatever action the user performs happens to modify the view state, then the code for that action belongs in the view model.

I like the MVVM pattern because of databinding, but I like databinding because it allows me to structure my code in a way that makes it easy to unit test most of my code. A big part of that structure is putting view state in one set of classes and model state in another.

I think that many times that people try to implement MVVM, they're really implementing a model-view relationship solely for the purpose databinding. That's fine, because there's no reason to maintain abstractions if they don't provide you with a clear benefit.

So, the answer to your question is what are you trying to achieve with your view models?

Databinding? Put the code wherever you feel like it.

Testability? Abstractions that provide separation of concerns? A model that is pure and free from view baggage?

Then put it in the view model.

Comment: I inherited a navigation control that has three groups. Each group is done differently. One is a mess and has both view and view-model inter-twined, a can of worms. One has no view-model, and the other does everything in the view-model. I wanted data-binding, but the "mess" is too bad. Testability is not a goal. At this point, I just want create some kind of consistency.

Comment: From you first paragraph, it seems the View is responsible. If I have an "Outlook" navigation then there is no view state.

Comment: @AMissico - I'm not sure what "Outlook" navigation means, but if the user clicks on something and the closes your application and reopens it and it doesn't look exactly the same... then you have view state. If you want to test this action... you have view state.

Comment: @AMissico - If you aren't testing, then I wouldn't worry about it too much. Abstractions are a pain and can obfuscate logic.

Comment: User clicks something, a dialog displays, edits made, dialog closes, nothing changes in the navigation pane. User clicks another thing, a report is display, and so on. Behavior like Outlook's navigation pane. The right pane, is were the action is.

Comment: @AMissico - are you using some sort of event aggregator or event bus?

Comment: There is a poorly implemented one. I need to replace it, and I was looking at "Mediator v2" at http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/mediator-v2-for-mvvm-wpf-and-silverlight-applications/ yesterday afteroon, which is strongly-typed. Any suggestions on use in this case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AMissico - I like MVVM light's implementation.

Comment: I ended up using MVVM Light. Small footprint and easy to implement and integrate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to have a ViewModel for every View I have, probably even a model as well. If you information to pass to other views then you really would need to do that through the ViewModel, if not then you can prolly get a way with just using the view to navigate. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Now if u want a outlook type feel, you can use a tab control which then can all be done under one view model.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about navigation with MVVM.

I found it very useful to watch this [video](http://dnrtv.com/dnrtvplayer/player.aspx?ShowNum=0182)

Here at about time 23:00 is explained an approach how to make elegant navigation with MVVM

Hope this helps